# Storage in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to pull multiple images from gallery and place in grid view , Unfortunately I am not able to do so, Can you help me with that. And also I made a folder in sd card and I m trying to store audio as well as photographs in the same folder. Can you help me with that as well?

I am using android 2.3.

So I have included this code inside the button click but on click of button it has created the folder but its not storing the file inside the folder. On click of the button every other thing is working, its opening the gallery and its calculating numpic. I am not sure why its not storing the file in CN Video folder.

public void onClick(View v) {

```
            Intent pass_data = new Intent(MainRecord.this, OpenGallery.class);
            pass_data.putExtra("numpic",numpic);
            startActivity(pass_data);

            // Saving Audio recorded file to directory

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CNvideo");
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                //Write code for the folder exist condition

            }else {

                // create a File object for the parent directory
                File CNvideoDirectory = new File("/sdcard/CNVideo/");
                // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
                CNvideoDirectory.mkdirs();
                // create a File object for the output file
                String filename = getfilename();
                File outputFile = new File(CNvideoDirectory, filename);
                // now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }};
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: I have downvoted your question for two reasons; first is the same as @CommonsWare, the second is because you are asking multiple questions in one post.  SO is designed for one question per post and so I encourage you to edit this question to ask a more specific question regarding what you have tried so far when trying to pull images into a grid view and then start a new question outlining what you have done so far to save to SD card.

Comment: Your edit is a great improvement; but, if you can now edit again and say where it is going wrong (which line) and how (error thrown? not the expected outcome? something else?) I think you might start to get some real help with this...